# помогите построить фигуру

Tags: python

```
      `1
       21
       321  
       4321    
       54321     
       654321    
       7654321       
       87654321        
       987654321         
       87654321
       7654321
       654321
       54321
       4321
       321
       21
       1`
```

Comment: `print(*["".join(map(str, range(9-abs(i-9),0,-1))) for i in range(1,18)], sep="\n")`. Можете не благодарить.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    print(''.join(list(map(str, range(i, 0, -1)))))
for i in range(8, 0, -1):
    print(''.join(list(map(str, range(i, 0, -1)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

вариант 1:

```
for i in list(range(1, 9)) + [9] + list(reversed(range(1, 9))):
    print(*[j for j in list(reversed(range(1, i + 1)))], sep='')
```

вариант 2 (однострочный):

```
print(*[''.join(map(str, [j for j in list(reversed(range(1, i + 1)))])) for i in list(range(1, 9)) + [9] + list(reversed(range(1, 9)))], sep='\n')
```

вариант 3 (однострочный укороченный):

```
print(*[''.join(map(str, [j for j in range(1, i + 1)]))[::-1] for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]], sep='\n')
```

еще короче

```
print(*[''.join(map(str, range(1, i + 1)))[::-1] for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]], sep='\n')
```

еще чуть-чуть короче

```
print(*[''.join(map(str, range(i, 0, -1))) for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]], sep='\n')
```

вариант 4 (самый короткий):

```
print(*[''.join(map(str, range(i, 0, -1))) for i in list(range(1, 10)) + list(range(8, 0, -1))], sep='\n')
```

вариант 5 (еще короче, от @GrAnd):

```
print(*[''.join(map(str, range(i, 0, -1))) for i in [*range(1, 10), *range(8, 0, -1)]], sep='\n')
```

вариант 6 (еще на пару байтиков короче):

```
print('\n'.join(''.join(map(str, range(i, 0, -1))) for i in [*range(1, 10), *range(8, 0, -1)]))
```

вариант 7 (от колдуна @GrAnd):

```
[print("".join(map(str, range(9 - abs(i), 0, -1)))) for i in range(-8, 9)]
```

вариант 8 (еще более короткий, но менее универсальный):

```
[print("123456789"[:9 - abs(i)][::-1]) for i in range(-8, 9)]
```

и даже так:

```
[print("987654321"[abs(8 - i):]) for i in range(17)]
```

и еще на одну буковку поменьше:

```
[print("987654321"[abs(i):]) for i in range(-8, 9)]
```

Comment: Склеить range'ы можно используя меньшее количество символов - `[*range(1, 10), *range(8, 0, -1)]`. Но мой вариант всё равно остаётся короче _(даже если в нём везде расставить пробелы)_. :)

Comment: круто, не думал вообще про такую возможность

Comment: Ну и мой вариант (через abs) тоже чутка короче. `print(*["".join(map(str, range(9 - abs(i), 0, -1))) for i in range(-8, 9)], sep="\n")`

Comment: тогда мой еще чуть короче: `print('\n'.join("".join(map(str, range(9 - abs(i), 0, -1))) for i in range(-8, 9)))` :)

Comment: Ещё короче `[print("".join(map(str, range(9 - abs(i), 0, -1)))) for i in range(-8, 9)]` :)))

Comment: чертов колдун, что это за техника? никогда не встречал... а, понял, хитро

Comment: хорошо, еще более короткий вариант: `[print("123456789"[:9 - abs(i)][::-1]) for i in range(-8, 9)]`, хотя и не универсальный

Comment: на!!! `[print("987654321"[abs(8 - i):]) for i in range(17)]` :))) а лучше так: `[print("987654321"[abs(i):]) for i in range(-8, 9)]
`